# Model pagination on list collection in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Lets say i have a table pagelabels which keep track of page labelled by user with a label -

The table i have is as below -

```
CREATE TABLE pagelabels (
    pageid text PRIMARY KEY,
    label list<string> // A list of label on this pageid
)
```

i want to show user 10 label initially on page sorted by insertion time on opening the page. When user asks for more labels by clicking on load more labels, i should return next 10 labels on this page.  How can i support such pagination scheme? Should I consider changing my Data model in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get your desired results by using current data model. With the current data model you have if you query with pageId, all labels will be returned at once as they are in single list. Also there is no provision to sort by insertion time.
A better data model could be

```
CREATE TABLE pagelabels (
pageid text,
insertion_time timestamp,
label string,
label_attribute1 string,
PRIMARY KEY (pageid, insertion_time, label));
```

)

With this data model and using paging from the drivers (for example see here for [Datastax Java Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/manual/paging/).